# "There are currently N bounties, worth X reputation" dynamic ad and the new sidebar width

Tags: discussion, advertising, sidebar, community-promotion-ads

You've probably seen this sidebar ad on one or more [community-ads](/questions/tagged/community-ads)-enabled Stack Exchange sites over the years:

[image: Active bounties]

The image is dynamically generated from a non-officially SE app that uses the Stack Exchange API to fetch the bounties from a given site.

As far as I understand, the rendered image automatically scales to the allotted ad space - when the sidebar ads were 220x250, it would render in the sidebar as a 220x250 image *while still looking quite oversized* in the [community-ads](/questions/tagged/community-ads) meta (as it does right here).

With the new 2016 campaign starting, can we test whether this awesome dynamic ad works with the new sidebar width?

Comment: is there a link to the app?  maybe a Git repo?

Comment: @Malachi no idea

Comment: @Malachi: There are at least two repos: https://github.com/kylecronin/Stack-Exchange-Bounty-Ad and https://github.com/51cards/Stack-Exchange-Bounty-Ad - sadly neither have a license or allow issues.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The reason that specific width and heights (300x250, or 600x500 for retina) are asked for when providing community ads is to avoid squashing by images not suited for that aspect ratio.

See, for example, your image would look like this in a community ad:

[image]

Yuck.

As to ask for the specific aspect ratio is so that it won't be squashed and instead of providing an aspect ratio, it'd be  simply easier to provide a specific height and width to meet.

Comment: I actually included it in the guidelines in the new threads, "300x250, or twice that for retina". Which translates to 600x500 as the general go-to.

Comment: Aw, so the app that's providing the image would have to be rebuilt to take into account the new aspect ratio then... I mean it *does* scale to the allotted space, it just *looks* squashed.

Comment: @GraceNote These images are hosted externally (I.e. Outside of stack.imgur). In the image requirements it says the ads must be hosted via the standard stack Imgur account. Is this an allowed exception the rules?

Comment: @angussidney Yes, it's something that's been worked out in the past. Pretty much the only exception though.

Comment: @GraceNote it *might* be something for a project to do things like have a dynamic advertisement for the twitter post (what was the last thing tweeted?) or /review (how many items are reviewable), or new questions, or bounties... lots of things that SE can do if they were to make some of their own dynamic adverts.

Comment: @MichaelT I would suggest posting as its own question as a feature-request :-)

Comment: The app has now been fixed to output an image with the new 600×500 dimensions.