# What's the official stance on the bounty ad?

Tags: discussion, images, advertising, imgur, community-promotion-ads

[Github repo of ad in question](https://github.com/kylecronin/Stack-Exchange-Bounty-Ad), [link to ad on codegolf.se](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/11415/46271), and [link to ad on scifi & fantasy.se](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/10583/57650).

This ad has been used more or less widely around the network. For those who don't know, it's an ad hosted by Kyle Cronin that shows the current number of bounties and their sum.

Here's an example: (this is the SFF one, because codegolf.se doesn't have any bounties at the moment)

[image: bounty]

This is what the image currently looks like for SFF, [here's a link to the updating version](http://stack-exchange-dynamic-ads.herokuapp.com/scifi.stackexchange.com/bounty.png).

Looks like this for no bounties:

[image: bounty2]

(the two in this post are static and won't change, and are hosted on imgur, just examples of what it looks like)

But most of this is beside the point, it's just some background info.

From the ads post:

> #### Image requirements
>
> - The image that you create must be 300 x 250 pixels, or double that if high DPI.
> - Must be hosted through our standard image uploader (imgur)

This is not hosted on imgur. Normally, the system blocks you from submitting it, but you can submit any imgur link and then ninja-edit (i.e. those edits that don't show in the rev history) into the auto-updating version.

What's the official stance? Is this ad allowed?

I'd assume that the imgur-only part is mostly for 1. to keep the ads up, because imgur doesn't go down often (as another image hosting site might) and 2. to prevent malicious websites changing the image to a nsfw one/clickbaity/spam ad.

Can we continue to use this ad?

Comment: If the ad is actually used ... isn't that your answer? Afaik that ad concept has been around for many years now

Comment: @Bart yeah, but what's the official SE stance? Just because they haven't stopped it doesn't mean they condone it. (related: chatbots)

Comment: At the very least, it seems that this could be used as an exploit to get past their requirements. SE could choose to make an exception for this ad, but the exploit isn't likely to be a good thing to leave as-is.

Comment: Related: [Why are the requirement for imgur hosted images being enforced this year? (2017 Community Promotion Ads)](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/290911/why-are-the-requirement-for-imgur-hosted-images-being-enforced-this-year-2017)

Comment: And here I thought this had something to do with paper towels.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Yes, this is officially allowed, as proved by [this comment](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/273044/there-are-currently-n-bounties-worth-x-reputation-dynamic-ad-and-the-new-side#comment887238_273045) from Grace Note: (Community Manager in Stack Exchange, in charge of the Community Promotion Ads)

> Yes, it's something that's been worked out in the past. Pretty much the only exception though

So it's allowed and can be safely used on any site until declared otherwise.